# OpenCV: How to use contrib modules on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos, opencv

I have built the iOS framework with contrib modules as outlined [here](http://xfanzone.me/opencv-for-ios-en.html) at the bottom and it all worked fine (simply copy the contrib modules you need and run `build_framework.py`. When looking at the framework, I see that the modules like `xfeatures2d` are there.
[image]

However, after adding the framework to my target, I cannot use them in XCode, it complains `file not found`.

[image]

Interestingly, XCode will autocomplete `#import <opencv2/xf` to `#import <openccv2/xfeaturesd2/>` but will not autocomplete the headers in that folder.

How can I make XCode acknowledge the presence of those headers?

**EDIT**: Turns out, I had another (older) version of `opencv2.framework` in `/Library/Frameworks` although I had explicitly added the one in `~/Library/Frameworks/`. It seems XCode always linked against the former, ignoring the latter, which makes it very strange that it would autocomplete the `xfeatures2d` folder in `#import` statements although the framework version used does not contain this folder.

Comment: @downvoter: Please elaborate what should be improved in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such a case, one should make sure which framework XCode links against and check whether the same framework in another version also resides in `/Library/Frameworks/` or some other default search location. I could not make XCode use the right one so I had to symlink to it.